# ffmpeg2theora oggfwd not working with icecast2

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg, mjpeg, icecast

I have a camera streaming (mjpeg) in http://192.168.x.x/image (where x are the rest of the IP). I start my icecast2 server (Ubuntu 10.10) and then I stream using:

```
ffmpeg2theora -f mjpeg http://192.168.x.x/image -o /dev/stdout - | oggfwd localhost 8000 password /test
```

The mountpoint is created but the video is not showing on Firefox. I do see the video box but it's just infinitely showing the "thinking" icon and video does not show.

If I download a proper ogg file and do

```
cat proper_ogg_file.ogg | oggfwd localhost 8000 password /test
```

I see the video on the icecast server's website.

In addition I did:

```
ffmpeg2theora -f mjpeg http://192.168.x.x/image -o test_video.ogg
```

Once I stop the process (CTRL+C) and go to my Desktop where the video is saved and open it with VLC or any other media player, it plays the portion of the stream that I allowed to be recorded all the way up to pressing CTRL+C.

If I take that file and use the previous method:

```
cat test_video.ogg | oggfwd localhost 8000 password /test
```

I get the same issue as when I was directly piping the camera to stdout and then to oggfwd. So therefore I assume this is a "conversion" to ogg issue? Can anybody help? Any idea why i can't do that?

Answer (score -3):

I found a solution. The solution is to use flumotion. It is a lot easier to use and works for what I needed it. I can provide information on how to use it if anybody needs to do so.

Thank you